# Retrieving time-code from video frame

Tags: java, c, video

I want to retrieve time-code corresponding to each frame in a video and display it as a ticker continuously while playing the video. How can this be achieved in a best possible way? Open to any programming language(but preferably C or Java).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a fairly difficult task without some layer of abstraction. For that I'd suggest you take a look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/). It's a pretty easy to use library and even has an example media player. I haven't used it for a while, so things may have changed, but definitely worth a look.

Comment: @VenkatagopalDodla Please use the "add comment" button to communicate. The "edit" button is for editing questions and answers. Anyway, like I said, I haven't used the library in a while, but I know they offer a video player as one of the examples.